# Hibernate + ehcache second level cache miss in simple example

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, ehcache

I use hibernate statistics for gathering information about 2 level cache miss or hits.
Why when I execute test module, I have only Second Level Miss but not Hits?
Why second level cache is not working in my example?

I have next hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.100.0:1521:rrr</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">ora</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">lll</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">ora</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="format_sql">false</property>
        <property name="use_sql_comments">false</property>

        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
        <property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">/ehcache.xml</property>


        <mapping class="com.ric.bill.model.bs.Lst"></mapping>
        <mapping class="com.ric.bill.model.bs.LstTp"></mapping>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And next ehcache.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="true"
    monitoring="autodetect" dynamicConfig="true">

    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir/ehcache" />

    <defaultCache maxEntriesLocalHeap="5000" eternal="true"
        timeToIdleSeconds="120" timeToLiveSeconds="120" diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="30"
        maxEntriesLocalDisk="10000000" diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" statistics="true">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </defaultCache>

    <cache name="billCache" maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000" 
        eternal="true" timeToIdleSeconds="0" timeToLiveSeconds="0">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </cache>

    <cache name="org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache"
        maxEntriesLocalHeap="5000" eternal="false" timeToLiveSeconds="120">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </cache>

    <cache name="org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache"
        maxEntriesLocalHeap="5000" eternal="true">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </cache>
</ehcache>
```

Also, next pom.xml:

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.journaldev.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>HibernateEHCacheExample</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<description>Hibernate Secondary Level Cache Example using EHCache implementation</description>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Hibernate Core API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- EHCache Core APIs -->
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-ehcache -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- EHCache uses slf4j for logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

And this simple entity:

```
package com.ric.bill.model.bs;

import javax.persistence.Cacheable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;

import com.ric.bill.Simple;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "LIST", schema="BS")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE, region="billCache")
@Cacheable
public class Lst implements java.io.Serializable, Simple {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Integer id; //id

    @Column(name = "CD", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private String cd; //cd 

    @Column(name = "NAME", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private String name; //Наименование 

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="FK_LISTTP", referencedColumnName="ID")
    private LstTp lstTp ; 


    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCd() {
        return this.cd;
    }
    public void setCd(String cd) {
        this.cd = cd;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public LstTp getLstTp() {
        return lstTp;
    }
    public void setLstTp(LstTp lstTp) {
        this.lstTp = lstTp;
    }

}
```

My test module:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session sess = sf.openSession();
        sess.beginTransaction();

        for (int a=1401; a<=1452; a++) {
            Lst lst = (Lst) sess.load(Lst.class, a);
            System.out.println(lst.getName());
        }
        for (int a=1401; a<=1452; a++) {
            Lst lst = (Lst) sess.load(Lst.class, a);
            System.out.println(lst.getName());
        }
        Statistics stats = sf.getStatistics();
        printStats(stats, 0);

        sess.getTransaction().commit();

        System.out.println("Complete!");

    }
}
```

output:

```
 Fetch Count=52
 Second Level Hit Count=0
 Second Level Miss Count=52
 Second Level Put Count=52
 Complete!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The level 2 cache is used to cache entity between different sessions. Here you are in the same session, so hibernate did not had to go to level 2 cache : it could get the entity from the session.

And as you see you're getting only 52 misses, not 104. Only the first for loop is generating those misses. Then hibernate is getting the entities, putting them in the session and the level 2 cache. On the second loop, it found them in the session and did not had to look at the level 2 cache, hence no hit nor miss generated.

To test level 2 cache, close the transaction and session at the end of the first for loop, and open new ones (tx and session) before the second loop.

Comment: Really! I close first session and open another and it works now: Fetch Count=52
Second Level Hit Count=52
Second Level Miss Count=52
Second Level Put Count=52
Complete!

Comment: Yes this is the use of second level caching. Be careful with it : now your entities are shared between threads.